# iPhone won’t shut off

Tags: iphone, power

My iPhone 5s just randomly stopped allowing me to shut it off with the power button. I don’t understand why but every single article online says that it’s a relatively common problem and the way to fix it is a hard reset. I’ve done a hard reset three times and it hasn’t started working again. Odd thing is, after it’s been hard reset it won’t turn back on unless it’s plugged into a charger (despite it being at 78%) it will just flash the white Apple logo every 5-10 seconds or so. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try restore it through iTunes. First of ALL you should back it up using iTunes or iCloud. If you own an iMac , iTunes app is a built one. 
If you don’t have a Mac download iTunes app to your computer and make an iTunes account. 
Then connect your iPhone to your Mac/windows PC - login to your iTunes account - back it up - when backup is complete, Restore it (there is a RESTORE button ).
This way your issue will be resolved IMO. Cheers.